# Jquery load error in IE 6

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this script to add a comment and to load the server response:

```
        $r="            $('#somestuff').hide();
            $('.button').click(function() {
 // validate and process form
 // first hide any error messages
 $('#somestuff').fadeIn(5000);
});
$('#subm').click(function() {
        // validate and process form
        // first hide any error messages
    $('.error').hide();

        var email = $('input#email').val();
        var id = $('input#id').val();
        if (email === '') {

      $('input#email').focus();
      return false;
    }
        var phone = $('textarea#body').val();
        if (phone === '') {

      $('input#body').focus();
      return false;
    }

        var dataString = '&email=' + email + '&body=' + phone + '&id=' + id;
        //alert (dataString);return false;

        $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/helpdesk/idejas/ratingupdate/',
      data: dataString,
      success: function(html) {
      $('#somestuff').html('<div id=\"message\" class=\"success large\"></div>');
        $('#message').html('Paldies par ieteikumu!').hide()
        .fadeIn(1500);
        $('#somestuff').hide('slow');
        $('#iddiv').show('slow');
        $('.comments').append(html);
        $('.comments li:last').fadeIn(1500);
      }
     });
    return false;
    });

"
 ;
```

Everything works fine in FF, Chrome, IE 7,8, but IE 6 breaks. It displays these chars: **?** and I have no Idea how to fix this. This is happening sitewide. What could be the problem? I ran it through JSLint, and fixed all the bugs.

Comment: What you've posted is not valid javascript. Show exactly what is the final javascript rendered in the browser without mixing it with server side language. That way it will be easier to determine the error. Also try indenting and formatting your snippet properly.

Comment: go to jsbin.com and put your example there, then share the link and we will test it and help you... don't assume we do all the work.

Comment: Could it be character encoding issues? Have you 'viewed source'? Can you force utf-8? etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not related to your question and I really don't mind getting downvoted just because I did not post this as a comment since most of the inexperienced people never bother to check the comments - They just scroll to the answers and get it over it.

I kindly request you to follow *the* (eternal) good programming practices.

I (not sure about others) get really put off when reading code which is not styled properly, forget its correctness.

Such badly indented code, badly chosen variable names (you have an HTML id called 'someStuff' - seriously?). The next time you try to make some changes to the code, you yourself would waste a few precious minutes trying to figure out what stuff were you trying to display using 'someStuff'!

And especially on a site like StackOverflow, where you need to explain your problem to the people as clearly as possible for the quickest and best solutions, is why your code (the best description of your problem) needs to be as clear as possible. Do take time to format your code in StackOverflow as well. It is totally worth it, trust me.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am aware of this, and have made amends. I have also found the answer to my question. The display of these chars is happening because of some weird misconfiguration of my server. On the production server everything is working just fine.